# Cannot resolve table name close to

Tags: mysql, sql, reference

I want to create a references to foreign table. but i'm getting the following error:

query:

```
CREATE TABLE category_ids (id INT, post_id INT,
                    INDEX par_ind (post_id),
                    FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES post(id)
                      ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2013-08-23 00:11:06 7f6f49e7b700 Error in foreign key constraint of table fun/category_ids:
FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES post(id)
                      ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB:
Cannot resolve table name close to:
(id)
                      ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB
```

posts table structure

```
    mysql> describe post;
    +-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
    | Field       | Type                  | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
    +-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
    | id          | int(11)               | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
...
    +-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
    22 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Possibly it thinks "post" is a reserved word, what if you qualified the post in your foreign key with back ticks (i.e. \`post\`(id)).

Comment: Have you got any way to check that your tables are correctly using INNODB and not something else ? (Even if you clearly wrote it, yes)

Comment: You can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to check the engine used for the referenced table.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Only InnoDB supports Foreign keys, MyISAM doesn't.
Even if it would, you cannot create relations between tables of different type.

Therefore you need to convert the table `post` into InnoDB. `ALTER TABLE post ENGINE = InnoDB;`

Comment: I need myISAM for fulltext index :(

Comment: You cannot have your cake and eat it too ;)

Comment: New version of mysql has `FULLTEXT` indexes for `InnoDB`

Comment: Man, MySQL and its crappy error messages. First it just tells you that it couldn't create the foreign key without any details. So you have to find out where the details are. Then it tells you it can't resolve a name of a table that obviously exists. So now the error can be anywhere. Thank god for Stack Overflow.

Comment: if anyone needs to convert their table using Laravel migrations, here is the command: `$table->engine = 'InnoDB';`

Answer (score 1):

This error can also come when parent table is partitioned. Removing partitioning from the parent table allows foreign constraint to be created without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me works with this.

```
CREATE TABLE category_ids (id INT, post_id INT references post(id),
                INDEX par_ind (post_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```