# I can't figure out why I'm getting a Cannot add foreign key constraint error

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, schema, primary-key

I'm working on a schema for a project and I'm trying to import it to my local host so I can work on writing some queries that will pull info from the database onto a webpage. I'm getting a `#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint` error, and it pertains to the use of `cities(city_id)` as a foreign key. I'm not sure what the problem is, they're both the same data type (`INT`) and `city_id` is the primary key of the `cities` table. I'm stumped here guys and I'm hoping somebody on here can lend a hand.

EDITED: So I got this working, but that's without the order table which I'll paste below the working schema.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cities;
-- Table for storing cities
create table cities (
    city_id INT(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    city_name VARCHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY(city_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS drivers;
-- table for Drivers registered in lyft database
create table drivers (
    driver_id INT(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fname VARCHAR(32),
    lname VARCHAR(32),
    address VARCHAR(32),
    contactnumber VARCHAR(32),
    driver_city INT(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(driver_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (driver_city) REFERENCES cities(city_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cars;
-- Table for storing cars information in lyft
create table cars (
    car_id INT(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    car_name VARCHAR(32),
    car_type VARCHAR(32),
    car_model VARCHAR(32),
    car_licencenumber VARCHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY(car_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customers;
-- Table for storing customers using lyft
create table customers (
    c_id INT(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    c_fname VARCHAR(32),
    c_lname VARCHAR(32),
    c_city INT(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (c_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (c_city) REFERENCES cities(city_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS owns;
--  Table stores which drivers are having which cars
create table owns (
    driver INT(100),
    car INT(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (driver,car),
    FOREIGN KEY (driver) REFERENCES drivers(driver_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (car) REFERENCES cars(car_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Table that I cannot add to database is below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS order;
-- Table stores which drivers are driving a customer
create table order (
    driver INT(100),
    customer INT(100),
    city INT(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (driver, customer, city),
    FOREIGN KEY (driver) REFERENCES drivers(driver_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (customer) REFERENCES customers(c_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (city) REFERENCES cities(city_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

When trying to add it via `phpmyadmin` I get the following error:

```
Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

    An expression was expected. (near "ORDER" at position 21)
    Unrecognized keyword. (near "ORDER" at position 21)

SQL query:

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ORDER

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER' at line 1
```

FINAL EDIT: I finally figured it out, my problem was that `order` is a reserved/key word in mysql so that was throwing an error. I changed it to `orders` and all is well. I'll post the final schema below incase anybody runs into the same trouble as I did.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cities;
-- Table for storing cities
create table cities (
    city_id INT(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    city_name VARCHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY(city_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS drivers;
-- table for Drivers registered in lyft database
create table drivers (
    driver_id INT(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fname VARCHAR(32),
    lname VARCHAR(32),
    address VARCHAR(32),
    contactnumber VARCHAR(32),
    driver_city INT(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(driver_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (driver_city) REFERENCES cities(city_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cars;
-- Table for storing cars information in lyft
create table cars (
    car_id INT(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    car_name VARCHAR(32),
    car_type VARCHAR(32),
    car_model VARCHAR(32),
    car_licencenumber VARCHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY(car_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customers;
-- Table for storing customers using lyft
create table customers (
    c_id INT(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    c_fname VARCHAR(32),
    c_lname VARCHAR(32),
    c_city INT(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (c_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (c_city) REFERENCES cities(city_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS owns;
--  Table stores which drivers are having which cars
create table owns (
    driver INT(100),
    car INT(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (driver,car),
    FOREIGN KEY (driver) REFERENCES drivers(driver_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (car) REFERENCES cars(car_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders;
-- Table stores which drivers are driving a customer
create table orders (
    driver INT(100),
    customer INT(100),
    city INT(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (driver, customer, city),
    FOREIGN KEY (driver) REFERENCES drivers(driver_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (customer) REFERENCES customers(c_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (city) REFERENCES cities(city_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: what engine are you using? The error is the same as there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391034/cannot-resolve-table-name-close-to

Comment: @LioraHaydont Apparently, it's InnoDB engine

Comment: @LioraHaydont Sorry, I've updated my schema to show the Engine, Charset, and Collate for each table.

Comment: Please put your answer into an answer not your question. After the minimal wait time please accept it to show you found a solution. Next time before you post a question please google your error message without your specific names. Read many answers of many SO hits. Read the manual about it & errors in general. Read & act on [ask] and [mcve]. Reduce your code until there is no error to locate an error.

Answer (score 0):

From the error `Cannot resolve table name`, I guess you are trying to create table `drivers` before you create table `cities`, that means you are referring a table which doesn't exist. So the solution is to create table `cities` first

Comment: Fixed, but still getting an error, here's the output: 
`Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html for correct foreign key definition.
------------
`

Comment: When importing via phpmyadmin I get this error: `#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Comment: @Anonymous23234720-12473 now you have modified the `city_id INT(100) UNSIGNED`  of table `cities` but  table `drivers` still `driver_city INT`, the data type should be identical, so should be `driver_city INT(100) UNSIGNED`

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo.

Comment: I've got my schema semi-working, but I can seem to add the `order` table. I've posted the error above in an edit.

Comment: @Anonymous23234720-12473 `order` is one of the MySQL reserved words, you should add `order` in back quotes ``

Comment: @Anonymous23234720-12473 refer to the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)